# Is It possible to add same constraint to multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, constraints, sp-executesql

I have generated some code to do this in multiple tables. Error I get doing this is:

*Variables are not allowed in the ALTER TABLE statement.*

I understand that. The code I've generated :

```
DECLARE
@tableName VARCHAR(50) = 'myTable',
@sql NVARCHAR(100),
@parameter1 CHAR(1) = 'A',
@parameter2 CHAR(2) = 'I'

SELECT @sql = N'ALTER TABLE '+@tableName+'
               ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Status
               CHECK (Status in (@parameter1, @parameter2))'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'@parameter1CHAR(1), @parameter2 CHAR(1)',@parameter1,@parameter2
```

I know it doesn't work. But I'd like if It is possible in some way, because I have a lot of tables to apply this.

NOTE:
- I have a code to get tables and names and everything, I just need some idea to add the char values in the string.

Comment: given that you're hardcoding your check values into the variables, why not just put them directly into the exec call? no point in using a variable if the value never changes. `exec sp_executesql @sql, N''A' char1(1), 'I' char(1) etc...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the same constraint, but not with the same name.  A simple way is just to leave the name out.  And, put the parameters directly in the query:

```
DECLARE
    @tableName VARCHAR(50) = 'myTable',
    @sql NVARCHAR(100),
    @parameter1 CHAR(1) = 'A',
    @parameter2 CHAR(2) = 'I';

SELECT @sql = N'ALTER TABLE @tableName
               ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK (Status in (''@parameter1'', ''@parameter2''))';

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@tableName', @tableName);
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@parameter1', @parameter1);
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@parameter2', @parameter2);

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

If you have to deal with this constraint in many tables, you might consider having a table with valid values of `status` and using a foreign key constraint instead.

Comment: I've considered that. But thats not my problem. The result of the @sql u put there is : 
ALTER TABLE myTable
ADD CONSTRAINT 
CHECK (Status in (A,I))

Note the state of CHAR values.
The correct would be:

ALTER TABLE myTable
ADD CONSTRAINT 
CHECK (Status in ('A','I'))

Comment: @CarlosAndres  . . . This query puts single quotes around the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this from this example i didn't test it, but it should work.

```
ALTER TABLE first_Table
Add Constraint first_Table_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (table1_id)
References second_Table (table2_id),
Add Constraint first_Table_UQ1 Unique (table1_id)
```